# What type of auth security implements Odoo 10

Tags: security, authentication, odoo, odoo-10

I am new in Odoo, and I don't have much knowledge of securities. I am reading about the authentication and authorization of OAuth and OpenID Connect for APIs. I like to implement some type of security in my Odoo API or know what type of security Odoo implements for its API.

I look in the Odoo documentation but I can't find what kind of authentication security Odoo implements, I only found that it implements the XMLRPC protocol.

I would like how to implement security in the Odoo API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Odoo [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html):

> The authentication itself is done through the `authenticate` function
>   and returns a user identifier (`uid`) used in authenticated calls
>   instead of the login.
>
> Calling methods
>
> The second endpoint is `xmlrpc/2/object`, is used to call methods of
>   odoo models via the `execute_kw` RPC function. Each call to `execute_kw`
>   takes the following parameters: the database to use, a string the user
>   id (retrieved through authenticate), an integer the user’s password, a
>   string ...

Translation: they do not implement an industry-standard protocol such as OpenID Connect for authorizing API calls .

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
"The authentication itself is done through the authenticate function and returns a user identifier (uid) used in authenticated calls instead of the login."
What type of security or protocol used for this.

Comment: @IsraTeneda Their own protocol which relies on their own "security"

Comment: Thanks so much, Can you refer some links to explain more about their security technically, Is their security enough for a sensible transactions(e.g: online payment transactions) API?

Comment: Their doc: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html . Not sure if their security is enough for online payments, it might be a good question for them.